# WinUI Custom Toggle Switch with intermediate event

Tags: events, uwp, switch-statement, toggle, winui-3

I have been scratching my head for some time over this.

I want to have toggle switch that fires an event when pressed and based on the event handler toggles if specific task is completed as expected.

**So far:**

1. I could only attach `PointerPressedEvent`,which works fine.
2. There seems to be no way to control toggling action for the switch on click.

**Question:**

1. Shouldn't it be possible to click the toggle switch and toggle only if the desired action/task/method is completed.

Is this kind of control even possible to make with WinUI/UWP?

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do it this way.
First of all, you need to install the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** NuGet package (v8.0.0-preview-4 or later) to make **MVVM** style easier.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="ToggleSwitchSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <CheckBox
            Content="Awesome task should success"
            IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsAwesomeTaskShouldSuccess, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsThreeState="False" />
        <ProgressRing HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsActive="{x:Bind ViewModel.AwesomeTaskCommand.IsRunning, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <ToggleSwitch
            x:Name="AwesomeToggleSwitch"
            IsOn="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsAwesomeTaskSuccessed, Mode=OneWay}"
            Toggled="AwesomeToggleSwitch_Toggled" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

namespace ToggleSwitchSample;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    private async void AwesomeToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Detatch the "Toggled" event to avoid multiple firing.
            this.AwesomeToggleSwitch.Toggled -= AwesomeToggleSwitch_Toggled;
            // Set the "IsOn" state to its previous state.
            this.AwesomeToggleSwitch.IsOn = !this.AwesomeToggleSwitch.IsOn;
            // Run the task and wait until it's completed.
            await ViewModel.AwesomeTaskCommand.ExecuteAsync(this);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Attach back the Toggled event.
            this.AwesomeToggleSwitch.Toggled += AwesomeToggleSwitch_Toggled;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ToggleSwitchSample;

[ObservableObject]
public partial class MainPageViewModel
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    // The CommunityToollkit-MVVM library will automatically create
    // "IsAwesomeTaskShouldSuccess" property for binding.
    private bool _isAwesomeTaskShouldSuccess;

    [ObservableProperty]
    // The CommunityToollkit-MVVM library will automatically create
    // "IsAwesomeTaskSuccessed" property for binding.
    private bool _isAwesomeTaskSuccessed;

    [RelayCommand]
    // The CommunityToollkit-MVVM library will automatically create
    // "AwesomeTasCommand" command.
    private async Task AwesomeTask()
    {
        bool awesomeTaskResult = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            bool result = false;
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            result = true;
            return result;
        });

        IsAwesomeTaskSuccessed = awesomeTaskResult && _isAwesomeTaskShouldSuccess is true;
    }
}
```

Comment: your idea of detaching the toggle event worked fine. I didn't know that was even possible.  Further, your MVVM code inspired me to migrate mine. Thanks :D.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, when the toggle switch is clicked the first time, you want to start a task and do some work. After the work is finished, then you want to change the status of the toggle switch based on the result instead of changing its status automatically, right?

I find a workaround for your requirement. Not sure if it's the best way but at least it is wokring.

1. put the `ToggleSwitch` inside a `UserControl`.
2. create a default style of  the `ToggleSwitch`.
3. find the swith part of the `ToggleSwitch` form it's style and set the **IsHitTestVisible** property as false. This will make the switch part not clickable.
4. Use the `UserControl` in your xaml and handle the Tapped event of the `UserControl`
5. when you click on the switch part of the `ToggleSwitch`, it will trigger the Tapped event of the `UserControl` so you could do your work without changing the switch.
6. after the work is done, you could manually set the **ToggleSwitch.IsOn Property** based on the result.

I made a simple sample, you could refer it and change it as you want.

**ToggleControl.xaml:**

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ToggleSwitchStyle1" TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContentForeground}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="System,TranslateX"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,-3,-7,-3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleSwitch">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOffPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOffPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOffPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOnPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOnPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOnPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOffPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOffPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOnPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOnPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOffPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOnPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchHeaderForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContentForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContentForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOffDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOffDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOnDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOnDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOffDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOnDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchAreaGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ToggleStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOnTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="DraggingToOffTransition" From="Dragging" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobCurrentToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OnToOffTransition" From="On" GeneratedDuration="0" To="Off">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOnToOffOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OffToOnTransition" From="Off" GeneratedDuration="0" To="On">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <RepositionThemeAnimation FromHorizontalOffset="{Binding TemplateSettings.KnobOffToOnOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TargetName="SwitchKnob"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Off"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="On">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="KnobTranslateTransform" To="24" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobBounds" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOn" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SwitchKnobOff" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ContentStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="OffContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OffContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="OnContent">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OnContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchHeaderForeground}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchTopHeaderMargin}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                              MinWidth="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchThemeMinWidth}"
                              Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="12" Width="12"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchPreContentMargin}"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchPostContentMargin}"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid x:Name="SwitchAreaGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchContainerBackground}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" Margin="0,5" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="OffContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OffContentTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Content="{TemplateBinding OffContent}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="OnContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding OnContentTemplate}" Grid.Column="2" Content="{TemplateBinding OnContent}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="OuterBorder" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOff}" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOff}" StrokeThickness="2" Width="44"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SwitchKnobBounds" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchFillOn}" Height="20" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Stroke="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchStrokeOn}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchOnStrokeThickness}" Width="44"/>
                            <Grid x:Name="SwitchKnob" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" Width="20">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="KnobTranslateTransform"/>
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOn" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOn}" Height="10" Opacity="0" Width="10"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="SwitchKnobOff" Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchKnobFillOff}" Height="10" Width="10"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Thumb x:Name="SwitchThumb" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                                <Thumb.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Thumb.Template>
                            </Thumb>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <ToggleSwitch Style="{StaticResource ToggleSwitchStyle1}" x:Name="MySwitch" Header="Toggle Switch Example" OffContent="Do work" OnContent="Working" />
</Grid>
```

**ToggleControl.xaml.cs:**

```
 public ToggleSwitch innerSwitch { get; set; }

    public ToggleControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        innerSwitch = MySwitch;
    }
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <local:ToggleControl x:Name="Test" Tapped="Test_Tapped" Width="300" Height="300"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    
    }

    public async Task<bool> DoSomething() 
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);

        return true;
    }

    private async void Test_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool result = await DoSomething();

        ToggleControl control = sender as ToggleControl;

        control.innerSwitch.IsOn = result;
    }
```